# How to create .chm file using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, chm

In my MFC Application 
Now I want to create .chm file using HTML Help files ie (.hhk, .hhp, .hhc) from MFC
Please help me how we can create .chm file or help file for each Control in my MFC Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML Help Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524402.aspx) include an [HTML Help Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524404.aspx) you can use to do the conversion.

Comment: But I want for each Control's Help means when I click on any control in my MFC Dialog Box and click F1 then it will show Focused Control's Help ie If OK Button is my selected Control and I press F1 then in the .chm file it will show the help page of OK Button only like this I want and thanks for your Suggestion